# Keyboard will not dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, xcode6

I have a view controller with a input box attached to the bottom. If the input is clicked, the keyboard will show up. This view controller is pushed from a table view controller. When I click back button to the parent table view controller and come back, the keyboard will show up automatically and hover on top of the view. I tried resignFirstResponder to hide the keyboard but it didn't work.

If I click the input, the keyboard will show up like this:

[image: Screen when input is click/touch]

Then I click the back button to its parent table view. Then I click a row in the table to enter this view again. The keyboard is still there and the input view is now under the keyboard.

[image: Keyboard still shows when enter view again]

EDIT1:

I tried Smiless's code. The keyboard will disappear gradually when the view appears. Is there a way to remove the slow motion disappearing?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: What are you calling the resignFirstResponder on?

Comment: I tried to call it on the text view.

Comment: Ok, can you please add the code where you're showing/hiding  the keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Try this one to dismiss the keyboard when the user taps somewhere else :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: @BlackFrog How is that a valid edit? You've changed there answer completely by making it your own. If you think it's wrong then add your own answer or tell them don't change someone else's completely. Please roll it back or I will.

Comment: I tested right now, the user can still edit the textfield (or move the cursor ) without the keyboard disappear

Comment: I rolled it back.  But I was trying to show @Smiless that they should give a little more of a complete answer.

Comment: @BlackFrog then comment don't go changing the answer completely that isn't what the edit feature is for and if they see that it is better then they can change their own answer. Note though I do think your answer was better it was just the wrong way of doing it.

Comment: It works. I put it to viewDidAppear. It will hide the keyboard when the view appears again. User will still see the animated keyboard hiding, do you know how to improve it?